# Move class name from child to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image, addclass

Looking to move the class name of an image to it's containing figure element using jQuery...

```
<figure class="wp-caption">
    <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
    <figcaption >A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

In particular I would like to move any img tag class name beginning with 'imghvr-' to it's containing figure, if that containing figure has the class name 'wp-caption'. The result would look like the following...

```
<figure class="wp-caption imghvr-hinge-up">
    <img class="" src="image.jpg">
    <figcaption >A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Hope that makes sense!) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems simple enough. Show your code so far so we know why what you've tried isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this

```js
$('img[class^="imghvr-"]').each(function() {
  var cl = $(this).attr('class');
  $(this).removeClass().parent('[class="wp-caption"]').addClass(cl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="wp-caption">
  <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
  <figcaption>A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: This doesn't test if the parent actually has the ```wp-caption``` class.

Comment: @Michael Oakley you are right, thanks. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Nenad. This appears to work perfect for me!

Comment: Is the `className` removed at `img` before checking if parent has `className` `.wp-caption`?

Comment: @NenadVracar https://jsfiddle.net/2cnn77ue/ Should  `<img>` at second `<figure>` have `className` removed?

Comment: @guest271314 OP said this works for him so i am not changing it but you can add this https://jsfiddle.net/2cnn77ue/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
$( 'img[class^="imghvr-"]' ).each( function() {
  var imghvrClass =  $(this).attr('class').match(/imghvr-.*/)[0]
  var $parent = $(this).parent()

  if ( $parent.hasClass( 'wp-caption' ) ) {
    $(this).removeClass( imghvrClass )
    $parent.addClass( imghvrClass )  
  }
})


<figure class="wp-caption">
    <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
    <figcaption >A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="wp-caption">
    <img class="imghvr-hinge-up2" src="image.jpg">
    <figcaption >A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".wp-caption img");

    for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
        var img = imgs[i];
        if(img.className.startWith("imghvr-")) {
            img.parentChild.classList.push(img.className);
            img.className = '';
        }

    }
```

Something like that. I didn't test.

Edit: As always there is smarter than me ^^

Comment: Too many mistakes in this code. Please test it before sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `.closest()`, `.addClass(function(){})`, `.is()`

```js
var c = "[class^=imghvr-]";

$("img" + c)
  .closest("figure")
  .addClass(function() {
    if ($(this).is(".wp-caption")) {
      var img = $(c, this);
      var imgClass = img[0].className;
      img[0].className = "";
      return imgClass;
    }
  })
```

```css
img[class^="imghvr-"] {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
figure[class*="imghvr-"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<figure class="wp-caption">
  <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
  <figcaption>A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="wp-caption">
  <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
  <figcaption>A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="wp">
  <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
  <figcaption>A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Alternatively, using `.toggleClass()`, `.is()`, `.find()`, `.attr()`

```js
var c = "[class^=imghvr-]";

$("figure.wp-caption").toggleClass(function() {
  var img = $("img", this);
  return img.is(c) ? img.attr("class") : false
}).find(c).attr("class", "");
```

```css
img[class^="imghvr-"] {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
figure[class*="imghvr-"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<figure class="wp-caption">
  <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
  <figcaption>A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="wp-caption">
  <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
  <figcaption>A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="wp">
  <img class="imghvr-hinge-up" src="image.jpg">
  <figcaption>A sample caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```